# Rewriting a number based URL using .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite a simple number based URL to a sub folder?

I want http://mysite.com/123 to redirect to http://mysite.com/en/123.

The number could be anything from 1 - 9999. My attempt in htaccess was:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /en/$1/ [R]
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Please try it like this:
RedirectMatch 301 ^(\d{1,4})$ /en/$1

Comment: Do you use the obligatory `RewriteEngine on`? Do any other rules work?

Comment: RewriteEngine is on and all other redirects are working fine

Comment: In order to solve this old issue (if still needed) what are the "other redirects" and where are you redirected when asking `http://mysite.com/123` ? (If question is outdated, please remove, or post an answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your syntax is right, I just remove slash in the end of line and it works:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /en/$1
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that this 3 lines are writen in your HtAccess File (sorry for mybad english)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
##


## Now the rewrite
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ ./en/$1
```