# Load a picture on website without the correct image path

Tags: php, .htaccess

I found a very intersting feature on a website which I would like to imitate but unfortunately have no approach how this was solved.

As an example I have the following image which can be loaded with the following link: https://cdn.babymarkt.com/babymarkt/img/158107/900/big-maxi-digger-gravemaskine-a097705.jpg

If you call the link without the image name defined f.e. https://cdn.babymarkt.com/babymarkt/img/158107/900/ the same image is still shown. You could even replace everything what comes after "900/" by any random text and the same picture would still be loaded.

For me it seems it is enough to call the correct folder to display the image. It is not required to load a specific file in this folder.

Would anyone have an idea how this kind of solution could be solved at best in php, css, html and or JQuery.

Comment: Use a rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to rewrite the url. Using htaccess you can do something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/babymarkt/img/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ /babymarkt/img/$1/$2/big-maxi-digger-gravemaskine-a097705.jpg [NC,L]
```

read about it on another post on upwork [Rewriting a number based URL using .htaccess RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460044/rewriting-a-number-based-url-using-htaccess-rewriterule)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)babymarkt/img/158107/900/ /babymarkt/img/158107/900/big-maxi-digger-gravemaskine-a097705.jpg [QSA,L]
```

or follow this tutorial on [How can I redirect and rewrite my URLs with an .htaccess file?](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-)